# PHP if/elseif statement not working as intended

Tags: php

I am trying to make an if/elseif statement work in php and everything seems to work just fine, besides if the "locid" is empty, or not present, i want to display a different query. Could someone help me figure out whats wrong with the code?

Basically, the if(empty($locid)) statement does not work. The page appears as blank.

This is the code:

```
if (isset($_GET['locid'])) {
    $locid = $_GET['locid'];
    if (empty($locid)) {
        $selectloc = "SELECT * FROM locations;";
    } elseif ($locid == 'all') {
        $selectloc = "SELECT * FROM locations;";
    } elseif ($locid == 'veterinary') {
        $selectloc = "SELECT * FROM locations WHERE location_cate='Veterinary';";
    } elseif ($locid == 'store') {
        $selectloc = "SELECT * FROM locations WHERE location_cate='Store';";
    } elseif ($locid == 'shelter') {
        $selectloc = "SELECT * FROM locations WHERE location_cate='Shelter';";
    } elseif ($locid == 'other') {
        $selectloc = "SELECT * FROM locations WHERE location_cate='Other';";
    } else {
        $selectloc = "SELECT * FROM locations;";
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain more clearly what's not working properly

Comment: If `$_GET['locid']` isn't present, then `$selectloc` is never going to be set, since you'll never enter the outer if statement. Combining `isset` and `empty` like this doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: I just did, i hope that makes more sense

Comment: @iainn, what would you suggest i do then?

Comment: Copy your `else` case to the outer statement, as well as the inner one. The `empty` case can probably be removed as well.

Comment: I just tried that and it seems to have worked! I can't believe i did not think of that. I want to mark your comment as the answer but that cant be done

Comment: This code could be reduced in size dramatically if your `$locid` matched the thing you're searching for. This could be boiled down to a handful of lines using a prepared statement with a placeholder value. In most cases it's just `WHERE location_cate=?` and then `$locid` can be bound, excepting the `'all'` case.

Comment: If the query string is `?locid` only, `$_GET['locid']` will be a zero-length string. and both `isset` and `empty` are true. In other news, using [switch](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) would make this code lots more pleasant to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a logical flaw in your *if* *else* construction.

First you check if the `GET` variabe is set and enter an *if* statement if that's the case. However, checking for an empty variable inside that makes no sense as you know when you have entered the statement, the variable won't be empty.

Therefore, you should move your empty logic into an else statement supplementing your *isset()* as the logic would be that either the variable is set, or it is not (i.e. empty).

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['locid'])) {
    $locid = $_GET['locid'];
    if ($locid == 'all') {
        $selectloc = "SELECT * FROM locations;";
    } elseif ($locid == 'veterinary') {
        $selectloc = "SELECT * FROM locations WHERE location_cate='Veterinary';";
    } elseif ($locid == 'store') {
        $selectloc = "SELECT * FROM locations WHERE location_cate='Store';";
    } elseif ($locid == 'shelter') {
        $selectloc = "SELECT * FROM locations WHERE location_cate='Shelter';";
    } elseif ($locid == 'other') {
        $selectloc = "SELECT * FROM locations WHERE location_cate='Other';";
    } else {
        $selectloc = "SELECT * FROM locations;";
    }
} else {
    $selectloc = "SELECT * FROM locations;";
}
?>
```

Comment: That's exactly how I got the code working! I didn't realize I had left the 'else' of the if(isset) empty!

Answer (score 3):

**You should enable error reporting.**

> Basically, the `if(empty($locid))` statement does not work. The page
> appears as blank.

*The page appears as blank* should be sounding the logical alarm bells.

The problem is that if `$_GET['locid']` is not set, then your query is still expecting `$selectloc` which contains an SQL string not undefined (having no error reporting, means no errors = white/blank page).

```
// default to this first, let the conditions overwrite it.
$selectloc = "SELECT * FROM locations;";

if (isset($_GET['locid'])) {
    $locid = $_GET['locid'];
    if ($locid == 'veterinary') {
        $selectloc = "SELECT * FROM locations WHERE location_cate='Veterinary';";
    } elseif ($locid == 'store') {
        $selectloc = "SELECT * FROM locations WHERE location_cate='Store';";
    } elseif ($locid == 'shelter') {
        $selectloc = "SELECT * FROM locations WHERE location_cate='Shelter';";
    } elseif ($locid == 'other') {
        $selectloc = "SELECT * FROM locations WHERE location_cate='Other';";
    }
}
```

could also be written like:

```
<?php

// default to this first, append the constraints
$selectloc = "SELECT * FROM locations WHERE 1=1";

if (isset($_GET['locid'])) {
    $locid = $_GET['locid'];
    
    if ($locid == 'veterinary') {
        $selectloc .= " AND location_cate='Veterinary'";
    } elseif ($locid == 'store') {
        $selectloc .= " AND location_cate='Store'";
    } elseif ($locid == 'shelter') {
        $selectloc .= " AND location_cate='Shelter'";
    } elseif ($locid == 'other') {
        $selectloc .= " AND location_cate='Other'";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. It make sense to me and I will look into it, but I'd like to add that I got the code working by adding an else statement to the if(isset).

Comment: This really needs to be packaged up into a function.

Answer (score 0):

If the ids differ only by the case, you can greatly simplify the code:

```
$locids = [ 'veterinary', 'store', 'shelter', 'other' ];
$whereClause = '';

$locid = $_GET['locid'] ?? null;
if (in_array($locid, $locids)) {
    $locationCate = ucfirst($locid);
    $whereClause = "WHERE location_cate='$locationCate'";
}

$selectloc = "SELECT * FROM locations $whereClause;";
```